# how to make a element in the DOM with a higher hierarchy?

Tags: jquery

There are some elements in the dom, the hierarchy is like this:

```
<div id='outter'><div id='middle'><div id='inner'></div></div></div>
```

how can i make the inner div be the direct child of outter div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append the inner div to the outer div using jquery

```
$('#outter').append($('#inner'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
    $('#outter').append($('#inner'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#inner').appendTo('#outter');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R9BHB/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#outter').append($('#inner'));
```